# How to calculate total no. of Q_id remains

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

1. `STUDENT_RESPONS(Q-NO, STD_ID,RESPONSE)`
2. `QUESTION(Q_NO, QUESTION,A,B,C,D)`

how to calculate total `Q_NO` which is not attp by student

```
SELECT COUNT(Q_NO) FROM QUESTION MINUS SELECT COUNT(Q_NO) FROM STUDENT_RESPONS
```

I want to subtract `Q_no` from from table `question` and `Q_no` from table `Student_response`

Comment: Can you show us some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: First normalise your schema

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the not in

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Question q
WHERE q.Q_NO NOT IN (
      SELECT Q_NO
      FROM STUDENT_RESPONS)
```

or else the left join

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Question q
LEFT JOIN STUDENT_RESPONS s ON t.Q_NO=s.Q_NO
WHERE s.Q_NO is NULL
```

These 2 queries will return all questions that have not been answered by students